# Canvas refresh not Working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgsmapcanvas, mapcanvas

The canvas is not showing the changes after 1 second. The point is visible only after the whole script gets executed.

Here is the Script:

```py
import time

def refresh():
    cachingEnabled = iface.mapCanvas().isCachingEnabled()
    for layer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        if cachingEnabled:
            layer.triggerRepaint()
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh() 

def spin(seconds):
    time_end = time.time() + seconds
    while time.time() < time_end:
        pass

canvas=iface.mapCanvas()
m = QgsVertexMarker(canvas)
m.setCenter(QgsPointXY(269614.47214304556837305,2099557.2543975617736578))
m.setColor(QColor(255,0,255))
m.setFillColor(QColor(255,255,0))
m.setIconSize(10)
m.setIconType(QgsVertexMarker.ICON_CIRCLE)
for i in range(5):
        m.hide()
        refresh()
        spin(1)
        m.show()
        refresh()
        spin(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use "flashFeatureIds" from "QgsMapCanvas" which is designed for that.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.getFeatures()
feature = QgsFeature()
features.nextFeature(feature)
iface.mapCanvas().flashFeatureIds(layer, [feature.id()])
```

You would need to transform your QgsVertexMarker to a QgsVectorLayer before, or maybe there is another way to flash without vector layer.

Comment: I think this will flash for limited time. Actually my long term goal is to animate a taxi along some points in a path (Showing the point at one point then moving on next point and hiding the previous point). I think this will not work for that.

Comment: So you should describe your full goal. Have a look to "refresh layer" in vector properties and then "display". You can set an interval for refresh. And use a geometry generator to make the feature changing opacity along the time. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jsYRxmnWkI

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are using

```
range(5):
```

Does this not suggest that it will accumulate the refresh 5 times? Therefore adding a refresh of 5 seconds, as opposed to 1? (actually, 10 seconds, because you spin() twice in the loop).

Try changing the range() to 1 and only putting calling spin() once.

Comment: I used range because I want to create a point blinking type of animation. And I am refreshing the canvas after the spin function. But its not refreshing , that is the main problem.

Comment: yes i have a funny feeling that because the refresh() calls are inside the for loop, that they aren't excecuting untilt he loop is exited. Test without the for loop to start with.

Comment: I have no idea, but I guess, this might never work. The Python inside QGIS might not be threaded, so the "refresh" is just sitting in a queue or something similar waiting for the end of the script. I already tried to make a feature blinking each after the other one with one second interval, it didn't work a long time ago.